# Git is throwing an error about untracked files on branch master

Tags: git

I accidentally deleted by git project and am trying to revive it. I am getting this error:

```
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
        .github/
        CHANGELOG.md
        LICENSE
        README.md
        docs/
        src/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present
```

What does this mean and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, Git only stores files that you have told it to store.  The typical name for this process is *tracking*, and that's typically done by running `git add` on the paths in question.

In your case, these files are *untracked*: that is, Git is not storing them in any way.  Since this is a new project, that's normal: you can optionally create a `.gitignore` file to ignore anything you don't want tracked and then run `git add .` to add everything in the directory to Git.  You should the commit the changes with `git commit`.

Note that if you have another copy of your repository (say, on GitHub), you may want to clone it to another directory and then copy any changes over top of it and commit them that way instead.  That way, you'd keep the commit history you had.